# A loop is returning an extra time more only when inside a function

Tags: javascript, list, function, for-loop, undefined

very new to this so sorry if I'm missing something incredibly simple.

I've been trying to write something which will return a list of the property number, the names of the property and all property values for an object, formatted as:

```
"n property - property value"
```

I'm sure I've gone about this in an entirely over-complicated way, but here's the code:

```
var person = {
    names: ["A", "B", "C"],
    dob: "D",
    age: 21,
    job: "E",
    car: ["F", 2, "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
    phone: "L",
    instrument: "M",
    parents: ["N", "O", "P"], 
    born: "Q",
    lives: "R",
    university: "S",
};

function lister (name) {
  for (i=0; i<(Object.keys(name).length); i++) {
  if (((Object.values(name)[i].constructor) == Array) === true) {
    for (x=0; x<(Object.keys(Object.values(name)[i]).length); x++) {
      console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(name)[i] + " - " + Object.values(Object.values(name)[i])[x]);
    }
  }else{
    console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(name)[i] + " - " + Object.values(name)[i]);
  }
}
};

console.log(lister(person));

for (i=0; i<(Object.keys(person).length); i++) {
  if (((Object.values(person)[i].constructor) == Array) === true) {
    for (x=0; x<(Object.keys(Object.values(person)[i]).length); x++) {
      console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(person)[i] + " - " + Object.values(Object.values(person)[i])[x]);
    }
  }else{
    console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(person)[i] + " - " + Object.values(person)[i]);
  }
};
```

The problem is, when I call the for loop inside `function lister (name)` it seems to run one extra time, giving me:

```
"0 names - A"

"0 names - B"

"0 names - C"

"1 dob - D"

...

"9 lives - R"

"10 university - S"

undefined
```

However, when the for loop is taken out of the function (as I have done at the bottom), it returns normally, not returning that extra "Undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(Object.values(name)[i].constructor) == Array) === true` srsly?

Answer (score 1):

That `extra` is not from the the loop but from the function call. A function return undefined if it is not explicitly returning anything, in the below snippet the function `lister` is returning `x` so instead of undefined you will see `x`

```js
var person = {
  names: ["A", "B", "C"],
  dob: "D",
  age: 21,
  job: "E",
  car: ["F", 2, "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"],
  phone: "L",
  instrument: "M",
  parents: ["N", "O", "P"],
  born: "Q",
  lives: "R",
  university: "S",
};

function lister(name) {
  for (i = 0; i < (Object.keys(name).length); i++) {
    if (((Object.values(name)[i].constructor) == Array) === true) {
      for (x = 0; x < (Object.keys(Object.values(name)[i]).length); x++) {
        console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(name)[i] + " - " + Object.values(Object.values(name)[i])[x]);
      }
    } else {
      console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(name)[i] + " - " + Object.values(name)[i]);
    }
  }
  return 'x'
};

console.log(lister(person));

for (i = 0; i < (Object.keys(person).length); i++) {
  if (((Object.values(person)[i].constructor) == Array) === true) {
    for (x = 0; x < (Object.keys(Object.values(person)[i]).length); x++) {
      console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(person)[i] + " - " + Object.values(Object.values(person)[i])[x]);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(i + " " + Object.keys(person)[i] + " - " + Object.values(person)[i]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how i would do that

```
 function lister(obj){
   let i = 0;
   for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)){
      if(Array.isArray(value)){
        for(const entry of value)
           console.log(i + " " + key + "-" + entry);
      } else {
        console.log(i + " " + key + "-" + value);
      }
      i++;
   }
}
```